# How do I put all fields in a query result into a geojson string?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, geojson

I have a PostGIS table containing U.S. Census tracts. It has a Multipolygon column, along with string columns containing info about each tract.

I have this query:

```
SELECT
    tractce,
    countyfp,
    statefp,
    ST_AsGeoJSON(geom) AS geom_geojson  
FROM theme_mapbasetracts 
WHERE ST_MakeEnvelope( -74.084246673584,40.67638769936645, -73.7572317504883,40.800601763990066) && ST_Transform(theme_mapbasetracts.geom,4326)
```

One row of semicolon-separated results looks something like this:

```
"002202";"061";"36";"{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[-73.982964,40.722671],[-73.980607,40.721678],[-73.978231,40.720674],[-73.978753,40.719934],[-73.979735,40.720235],[-73.981308,40.720709],[-73.982167,40.720969],[-73.983824,40.721473],[-73.982964,40.722671]]]]}"
```

How do I put the first three strings -- `"002202";"061";"36"` -- into the GeoJSON string?

Comment: cross-posted [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/269628/how-do-i-put-all-fields-in-a-query-result-into-a-geojson-string)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Export Feature GeoJSON from PostGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14514/how-to-export-feature-geojson-from-postgis)